# Passing CLI options to rollup via package.json

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, rollupjs

I am using this script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
}
```

And would like to dynamically pass options to the `rollup.config.js` file, such as `npm run build home`, where 'home' is a variable that will build a particular bundle.

I manage to get to the rollup config file using `"build": "rollup -c rollup.config.js"` and I can access 'home' within an array by using

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
```

but still, as it was doing before without the addition in the package.json script, I get the error `[!] Error: Could not resolve entry module (home).` and no bundle gets created.

Using `--home` in the CLI hides it completely in the 16.17 version of node I'm using (managed fine with 14.x) for whatever reason.

Going in circles as ever with existing answers online. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Adding `rollup.config.js` to `"build": "rollup -c"` is superfluous since `rollup -c` already relies on the config file. You can pass options in just the config file.

Comment: Nope, got it working. `--` is needed afterwards in the CLI, then `--home` and it will be visible in the `process.argv.slice(2)` array. No need for minimist, whatever it supposedly does.